# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID

Tags: android

I'm new to Android application development and I recently downloaded & installed Android 3.1 platform (API 12).

I'm going through the tutorial and I'm trying to run the 'Hello world' program (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

But it doesn't work, I end up seeing the locked screen on the emulator. When I try to unlock it, it shows the:

> "Force close"

error message & button.

I went through this forum for answers and I checked the LogCat output. I found an exception there but I'm not sure how to fix the issue. Can some one please help me out?

**Exception stack trace:**

> WARN/ResourceType(162): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030015 (t=2 e=21) in package 0 (error -75)
>   DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(162): Shutting down VM
>   WARN/dalvikvm(162): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030015
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030015
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2039)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:389)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:336)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(162):     ... 11 more
>   WARN/dalvikvm(162): threadid=3: spin on suspend #1 threadid=10 (pcf=0)

**Hello World program:**

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(R.string.hello);
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

**layout/main.xml:**

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello" /&gt;
```

Thank you
Keerthi

Comment: Do you have string 'hello" in your /res/values/string.xml file ?? The best way to track this down will be to search in R file for 0x7f030015 and that to locate where is the problem

Comment: What do you have in your "string.xml" file?

Comment: If it wasn't in xml, it would not compile.

Comment: The content of my strings.xml file is pasted below

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloAndroid!</string>
    <string name="app_name">HelloAndroid</string>
</resources>

Comment: I dont have 0x7f030015 in R.java file